# How to know exactly which function/method/object is being called?

Tags: python, parsing

I want to write a program to get the exact line number of call being made.

```
class A:

     def method():
         return None


def method(x,y):
    return(y)


y = A(1,2)

a = y.method()
method(x,y)
```

I want a program that takes the python.py and line (or line number) and then output the sequence of code e.g :

```
def someMethod(file,line):
  #do something with code

someMethod('python.py','method(x,y)')
someMethod('python.py','y = method()')
```

Output should be :

```
def method(x,y),line_no
def method(),line_no
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @bereal Sorry, added the edit

Comment: I think you are trying to do runtime introspection, 
have a look at this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html

Comment: @simic0de Well I looked into it but runtime introspection only refers to type checking of grammar . I dont want to type check but actually want to check which lines of code are actually being executed . I got the "trace" module that actually does the same but I want to do it from scratch. It would be very nice if anyone can cite some sources.